# How to bypass per socket speed limit of my isp?

Tags: internet, isp

well my isp slows down the internet by puting per socket speed limit from evening till midnight total speed of connection stays ok if something i am download uses multiple socket but things that use 1 socket are like very slow around  40 kb/s speed youtube does not even play at 240p ( normally it works at 1080p ) i tried downloading things with IDM and speed go very slow if i use 1 connection to the file is there anyway i can by pass this limit ? i have vps server outside the countryi have openvpn installed on it but it does not help

Comment: What you want will contravene your ISP's terms and conditions of service. This site will not help you to do that. If you don't like their service, change your ISP.

Comment: i have only one isp in my area